# How to access Object array file into react component?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-5, webpack-4

I am trying to access an object array file within src folder eg: data.js(Object array only) this file into my app.js(react component)

in first scenario 1.I have tried this problem using react in

> src--[app.js(component)/data.js(object array)].

When I was run it shows me an error like

> (TypeError: _data__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default.a.map is not a function)means null array/undefined.

in second scenarios 2. when I add object array in app.js within the same page its shows me perfect result. without an error but trying from another file like data.js it taking null array I have used to `stringify()` and JSON parser but no result

Object array file data.js ->

```
const datas=[
    {
    "id":"1",
    "firstname":"sam",
    "lastname":"parkar"
    },
    {
    "id":"2",
    "firstname":"julee",
    "lastname":"fransic"
    }
    ];
```

react component app.js ->

```
import React from 'react';
import  datas from './data';
import  DataInfo from './DataInfo';
function App () {
 const appdata=datas.map( inner => inner.id + inner.firstname + inner.lastname)
//print on console
 console.log(appdata)
    return (
     <div className="App">
           <p>App js page</p>

              {appdata} 

      </div>
    )
  }
export default App;
```

error ->

```
TypeError: _data__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default.a.map is not a function
  21 | return (  
  22 |   
  23 |   
> 24 |   <div className="App">  
     |  ^  25 |   
  26 |        <p>App js page</p>
```

actual result:-
App js page

> 1samparkar2juleefransic
>   and on console
>   (2) ["1samparkar", "2juleefransic"]
>   0: "1samparkar"
>   1: "2juleefransic"

Comment: Sidenote: "Data" is already a plural word, "Datum" being the singular form of the word. So "Data" never takes an "s".

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Make sure you export the `datas` correctly

```
export const datas=[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "firstname": "sam",
    "lastname": "parkar"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "firstname": "julee",
    "lastname": "fransic"
  }
];
```

And in app.js call it like this:

```
import  {datas} from './data';
```

Comment: Having imported datas, how would you call just "firstname"s?

Comment: @Deborah you want to get an array of first names? then `const firstNames = datas.map( e => e.firstname)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use JSON file like this:

datas.json

```
[
    {
    "id":"1",
    "firstname":"sam",
    "lastname":"parkar"
    },
    {
    "id":"2",
    "firstname":"julee",
    "lastname":"fransic"
    }
]
```

In app.js:

```
import datas from './datas.json';
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JSON file then save that file as datas.json

Now in your app.js file use `<datas/>` instead of `{datas}`.

you can use `{datas}` when you are using it in a jsx attribute. for example-

`<textarea name="JSON" value={datas} />`.

but in your case, you should use `<datas />`.

Comment: I have tried your solution and cheers it works thanks a lot! +1